# Java Map Replace Value String If Map Contain This Value

Tags: java

**Java Map**
Key : Y Value : X
Key : Z Value : X+Y

So Should Value After Replace 
Key : Y Value : X
Key : Z Value : X+X

Because Y = X 
And Z Contain X+Y and Y Equal X ...etc

```
 Map<String , String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("x", "");
    map.put("y", "x");
    map.put("z", "x+y"); 

    System.out.println("Map :" + map);

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        Object key = entry.getKey();
        Object val = entry.getValue();
        System.out.println("Map Values " +  key + " Value " + val);
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: yes how Can Do This Replace 
value  Key :  Z  Value : X+Y
became Key :  Z  Value : X+X
Because Key : Y  Value  X

Comment: It's still unclear to me what you're trying to accomplish.  Can you write some code that shows an example of what you want to happen?

Comment: check code This example

Answer (score 1):

Calling `map.put("key", "value")` with a key that already exists in the map will replace its value with the new one. So in your example you could do: `map.put("z", "x+x");` to replace the value of key `"z"` with `"x+x"`

Comment: i don`t need override on  key , value  map 
i need check with condition within loop 
to return result after replace 
because ,i get this equation from user , so i need replace value automatically 
with out override in map values

Comment: @mohamedessam did you read matt's answer? If you call `map.put(key, value)` and the **key already exists, it REPLACES THE VALUE** with the new one.